# Let $S = \{(f,g) \in F \times F \mid f \in O(g)\}$ Prove that $S$ is a preoder, but not a partial order.

Tags: functions, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

> Let $F = \{f \mid f : \mathbb Z^+ \rightarrow \mathbb R\}$. For $g \in
>  F$, we define set $O(g)$ as follows:
>
> $$O(g) = \{f \in F \mid \exists a \in \mathbb Z^+ \exists c \in
>  \mathbb R^+ \forall x > a (|f(x)| ≤ c|g(x)|)\}$$
>
> Let $S = \{(f,g) \in  F  \times F \mid f \in O(g)\}$ Prove that
>   $S$ is a preoder, but not a partial order.

My attempt:

We need to show that $S$ is:

1. Reflexive.
2. Transitive
3. Not symmetric

1.

Take $f \in F$. Let $a$ be some positive number and $c = 1$.

Then clearly for all $x > a$ we have

$$|f(x)| = |f(x)|$$

Hence $(f,f) \in S$, and $S$ is reflexive.

2.

Take $(f,g),(g,t) \in S$.

Then exists some $a_1,c_1$ such that for all $x > a_1$

$$|f(x)|≤ c_1|g(x)|$$

And there exists some $a_2,c_2$ such that for all $x > a_2$

$$|g(x)|≤ c_2|t(x)|$$

Let $d \in Z^{+}$ such that $d > a_1$ and $d > a_2$. Then for all $x > d$ we have:

$$|f(x)|≤ c_1|g(x)|$$
$$|g(x)|≤ c_2|t(x)|$$

And thus

$$\frac{1}{c_1}|f(x)|≤ |g(x)| \implies$$
$$\frac{1}{c_1}|f(x)|≤ c_2|t(x)| \implies$$
$$|f(x)|≤ c_2c_1|t(x)|$$

Hence for all $x > d$ there exists scalar $c_1c_2$ such that

$$|f(x)|≤ c_1c_2|t(x)|$$

meaning that $(f,t) \in S$, and $S$ is transitive.

3.

Consider $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = x^2$

Let $c = 1$ and $a = 2$. For all x > 2, $|x| < |x^2|$, hence $f \in O(g)$ and $(f,g) \in S$.

Now suppose that $g \in O(f)$. Then exist some $a,c$ such that

$$|x^2| ≤ c|x|$$

for all $x > a$

Take arbitrary $x > c$ and $x > a$,

Then $x^2 > cx$, which contradicts our assumption that for all $x > a$

$$|x^2| ≤ c|x|$$

holds.

Hence $g \notin O(f)$, and $(g,f) \notin S$, which means that $S$ is not symmetric.

---

Is it correct?

Comment: The proof for being a preorder looks fine. However, to show that it's not a partial order, what you should be showing is that it is not *antisymmetric* (instead of not symmetric)

Comment: @platty, so in other words, I need to show that there exist at least two functions $f,g$ (where $f ≠ g$), such that $(f,g) \in S$ and $(g,f) \in S$, correct?

Comment: Yep, that'll be enough.

Comment: @platty, thanks for the review!